# XAML - Multiple ColumnSpans in one row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Completely new to XAML and need some help. Is it possible to use more than one ColumnSpan in a single row? I tried the code below and it does not work. It puts everything in the first spanned cell. What I am trying to do is reduce 8 columns to 4 evenly distributed in width.

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Switch Input Ch.A</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Swith Input Ch.B</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Switch Output Ch.A</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Switch Output Ch.B</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the column with the [`Grid.Column` attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.column(v=vs.110).aspx) (the default is 0 which is why everything is ending up in the first column):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Switch Input Ch.A</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Swith Input Ch.B</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Switch Output Ch.A</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Switch Output Ch.B</TextBlock>
```

Note for spans, this is the *starting* column/row. So the first `TextBlock` here starts in column 0 and spans across 2 columns (ending in column 1).